# Browser which loads external links last

Tags: browser

Do you know any internet browser that loads external links (like ads not local files) lastly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you bothered by adds? In that case, use [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/) browser, but also install [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/).

Comment: Yeah.. better browsers use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom or https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/noads/1.0.8/?display=en

Comment: I didn't know that something like that was ever created! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many text based simple web-browsers like [links](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLinks_(web_browser)&rct=j&q=links%20web%20browser&ei=5V5VTYLANITCswa5z8XjDA&usg=AFQjCNGmY2-9nhOiRd-Fu0My2gaphiN-Eg&cad=rja) and [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29).

Comment: I don't mean not to download them. I just hate when adds are loaded firstly and I want browser to reverse it.